# linear regression model fits poorly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I am trying to fit a model on a dataset of one feature in column 1 and a ones vector appended at column 0. No matter what i try, curve fits poorly to the data.

Here's the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

col = ['id','ri','na','mg','al','si','k','ca','ba','fe','glass_type']
data = pd.read_csv('glass.data', names=col, index_col='id')

x = np.array(data)[:, 0]
x = x.reshape(np.size(x), 1)
y = np.array(data)[:, 3]
y = y.reshape(np.size(y), 1)


# initialising
m = np.size(x)

# appending ones vector in x
one = np.ones([m, 1], dtype=float)
x1 = np.append(one, x, axis=1)

# weight matrix
theta = np.zeros([2, 1])

i_list = []
j_l = []
error = np.zeros([m, 1])


# gradient descent
for i in range(3500):
    h = x1.dot(theta)
    error = h - y
    theta = theta - (0.0001/m) * np.sum(x1.T.dot(error)) + (1.5/m) * np.sum(np.sum((theta[:, 1:2])**2))
    i_list.append(i)
    j = (1/(2*m)) * np.sum((h-y)**2)
    j_l.append(j)


# plotting
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(x, y, '.r')
plt.plot(x, x1.dot(theta), '-b')

plt.subplot(1,2, 2)
plt.plot(i_list, j_l, '-g')

plt.show()
```

[This how the data fits (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fny1N.png)
please suggest me ways to improve it. Thank You :)

Comment: That data doesn't look like a line can fit it. It seems to have little to no correlation and it clusters around that point in the center. Try changing the parameters you are putting in or the regression model.

Comment: @primusa i used scikit learn to fit the data and it was fitting it very well.

Answer (score -1):

First of all. Theta has to be reduced by regularization on every update. That the main idea of regularization but you take the sum.

PS. Also don't forget about large regularization parameter where in result you will get high bias. In this situation try different level of regularization (0.03, 0.3, 3, 30, 300). I mean try to put another lambda there:

[image: regularization]

For example:

```
theta = theta - (0.0001/m) * np.sum(x1.T.dot(error)) + (0.15/m) * np.sum(np.sum((theta[:, 1:2])**2))
```